# Jenkins - Copy script from Local folder to Workspace - Error 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null'

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, copy

I am new to Jenkins & Powershell, I'm trying to execute my Python script as a Post Build Action step through an already existing Jenkins job.

I am using PowerShell in Jenkins Build Step
powershell 'copy "${ Mylocalpath\JenkinsPythonscript.py}" ${Workspace}'

Then in the Post Build Action Step, I gave,
execfile(JenkinsPythonscript.py)

When I execute the job, I get the following error

```
12:20:26 Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
12:20:26 At line:1 char:6
12:20:26 + copy ${ C:\Users\somuj\PycharmProjects\TestProject\JenkinsPythonscript.py} ${Wor ...
12:20:26 +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
12:20:26     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
12:20:26     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCom 
12:20:26    mand
12:20:26  
12:20:26 Build step 'PowerShell' marked build as failure
12:20:26 [PostBuildScript] - [INFO] Executing post build scripts.
12:20:26 [gNS_Reports_Nexis_Cert1_Regression] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\devops\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2116124088026791482.bat
```

What I am doing wrong? Can someone help? I referred to different answers under the same topic, but not to locate the error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVhyF.png)

Comment: Are you doing this within powershell? The syntax is wrong. It should be `Copy -Path "C:\Users\somuj\PycharmProjects\TestProject\JenkinsPythonscript.py" -Destination b"\\mydestination\in\UNC\form\"` Powershell has its own use for the dollar sign (`$`) and (`{ }`) symbols, don't confuse them for the syntax on the other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `copy` command of windows. You need to replace `\` with `\\` when accessing paths in windows :
Workspace can be accessed using `%WORKSPACE%`

```
copy /Y <Source> <Destination>
copy /Y <SourcePATH> %WORKSPACE%\\
```

[image]
Enter command:

```
copy /Y C:\\Users\\somuj\\PycharmProjects\\TestProject\\JenkinsPythonscript.py %WORKSPACE%\\
```

Comment: Not working still. Its not able to find the path. Will Jenkins locate the path in my local system ??  "10:29:57 c:\jenkins\workspace\Dev\gNS\TestAutomation\gNS_Reports_Nexis_Cert1_Regression>copy /Y C:\\Users\\somuj\\PycharmProjects\\TestProject\\Final\\JenkinsPythonscript.py c:\jenkins\workspace\Dev\gNS\TestAutomation\gNS_Reports_Nexis_Cert1_Regression\\ 
10:29:57 The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @user16120973 Did you use the execute with windows batch command step?I executed the same command and it copies the file . Is this your exact path ``c:\\Users\\somuj\\PycharmProjects\\TestProject\\Final\\JenkinsPythonscript.py``

Comment: yes that is my exact path. I am not sure how to attach a screenshot here.. I have added a link of image in my question.

Comment: As Jenkins runs on a server, but my Python code is in my machine. My doubt is will Jenkins be able to access my local path ?

Comment: @user16120973 so command that I shared is correct but you would need to run on that machine if your scripts exists there .